# Installing a MariaDB connector on Tableau Desktop

Tags: mariadb, tableau-api, connector, tableau-desktop

I'm on `MacOS` and I'm trying to install a `MariaDB Connector` on Tableau Desktop. But I keep getting this error message :

[image]

I followed the instructions by installing the `MariaDB ODBC driver` from the official website. After its installation I placed the driver folder under `/User/username/Tableau/Drivers`.

Although, I keep getting the same error.
Do you have an idea on how to correctly install a `MariaDB` connector for Tableau on MacOS ?

Comment: The standard MariaDB Mac download is an installer (a *.pkg file) not a raw driver. Did you run the pkg or just move it? And which Tableau version are you working with as I thought Tableau bundled that driver with most recent versions.

Comment: I ran the mariadb connector pkg file. And I'm working with Tableau 2020.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to configure iODBC to recognise MariaDB Connector/ODBC as a Driver:

1. Install [iODBC][1]http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads
2. Modify the configuration file /Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini as the following:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver = installed

[MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.1
Driver=/Library/MariaDB/MariaDB-Connector-ODBC/libmaodbc.dylib
Threading=0
```